# Import XML URL Creation

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I would like to Create this URL automatically in a way that means I do not have to add more to this `IMPORTXML` function when I want to add more typeids. I would like it to work in a more automatic way, such as changing when a new typeid is added to a list of typeids.

Below is what I have so far but I am not sure how to make it an automatic process.

```
=IMPORTXML(CONCATENATE(Math!$B$3, B2,"&typeid=", B3,"&typeid=", B4,"&typeid=", B5,"&typeid=", B6,"&typeid=", B7,"&typeid=", B8,"&typeid=", B9,"&typeid=", B10,"&typeid=", B11,"&typeid=", B12,"&typeid=", B13,"&typeid=", B14,"&typeid=", B15,"&typeid=", B16,"&typeid=", B17,"&typeid=", B18, Math!$C$3), "//sell/min")
```